# Как собрать CMake`ом связку zlib + libpng и получить libpng в виде DLL

Tags: cmake, zlib, libpng

Я собираю CMake`ом связку zlib + libpng, на выходе получаю:

1. статическую и динамическую zlib;
2. статическую libpng;

Сборка libpng DLL крашится с выводом компоновщика:

> png.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflateReset
> referenced in function png_reset_zstream [D:\Projects
> temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngrutil.obj : error LNK2001:
> unresolved external symbol inflateReset
> [D:\Projects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] png.obj : error LNK2019:
> unresolved external symbol adler32 referenced in function
> png_compare_ICC_profile_with_sRGB [D
> :\Projects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] png.obj : error LNK2019:
> unresolved external symbol crc32 referenced in function
> png_calculate_crc [D:\Projects\temp\bu ild\libpng\png.vcxproj]
> pngread.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflateEnd
> referenced in function png_destroy_read_struct [D:\P
> rojects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngrutil.obj : error LNK2019:
> unresolved external symbol inflate referenced in function png_inflate
> [D:\Projects\temp\b uild\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngrutil.obj : error
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflateReset2 referenced in
> function png_inflate_claim [D:\Pro
> jects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngrutil.obj : error LNK2019:
> unresolved external symbol inflateInit2_ referenced in function
> png_inflate_claim [D:\Pro jects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj]
> pngrutil.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> inflateValidate referenced in function png_inflate_claim [D:\P
> rojects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngwrite.obj : error LNK2019:
> unresolved external symbol deflateEnd referenced in function
> png_destroy_write_struct [D: \Projects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj]
> pngwutil.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol deflateEnd
> [D:\Projects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngwutil.obj : error
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol deflate referenced in function
> png_compress_IDAT [D:\Projects\ temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj]
> pngwutil.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol deflateReset
> referenced in function png_deflate_claim [D:\Proj
> ects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj] pngwutil.obj : error LNK2019:
> unresolved external symbol deflateInit2_ referenced in function
> png_deflate_claim [D:\Pro jects\temp\build\libpng\png.vcxproj]
> D:\Projects\temp\build\libpng\Release\libpng16.dll : fatal error
> LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals [D:\Projects\temp\bui
> ld\libpng\png.vcxproj] png-fix-itxt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
> external symbol crc32 referenced in function main
> [D:\Projects\temp\build\ libpng\png-fix-itxt.vcxproj]
> D:\Projects\temp\build\libpng\Release\png-fix-itxt.exe : fatal error
> LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [D:\Projects\temp
> build\libpng\png-fix-itxt.vcxproj]

Вот минимальный CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

set(PROJECT_NAME test)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libpng ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libpng)

set(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(PNG_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(PNG_SHARED ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(PNG_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${zlib_SOURCE_DIR} ${zlib_BINARY_DIR})

add_subdirectory(zlib)
add_subdirectory(libpng)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Статическая версия( файлы
.lib ) же успешно собирается

Answer (score 0):

Что ж, ответов не дождался, накостылил сам. Однако, работает безупречно, собираются как статик, так и динамик либы, в Windows и Linux

```
# ZLIB
set(ZLIB_ROOT $ENV{MSExternal}/multiplatform/zlib)
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY zlib)
add_subdirectory($ENV{MSExternal}/multiplatform/zlib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib)

if(UNIX)
  set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${zlib_SOURCE_DIR} ${zlib_BINARY_DIR}) # zlib
  
  target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE          # libpng
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libpng
  )
endif()

# LIBPNG
set(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(PNG_SHARED ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(PNG_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(PNG_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory($ENV{MSExternal}/multiplatform/libpng ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libpng)

install(TARGETS zlib EXPORT libpng)
```

Comment: А почему нельзя официальные модули использовать? [FindZLIB](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindZLIB.html), [FindPNG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPNG.html).